# wifi not working in raspberry pi 2

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I want to setup multiple network for wifi. One for my home and another for my office. I took the reference from stackoverflow but it did not work in mine. It works if i use the ethernet but not when using wifi dongle. Here how i setup for multiple wifi

/etc/network/interfaces

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf  /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf


allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf  /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

/etc/wpa_supplement/wpa_supplement.conf

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
        scan_ssid=1
        ssid="MiRouter"
        psk="4444333221"
        id_str="home"
        priority=1
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}

network={
        ssid="companyssid"
        psk="password"
        id_str="office"
        priority=2
}
```

I am using raspberry pi 2 and OS is raspbian stretch. What have i missed here?

Before the configuration was following and it was working

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0


iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-scan-ssid 1
   wpa-ap-scan 1
   wpa-key-mgmt WPA-PSK
   wpa-proto RSN WPA
   wpa-pairwise CCMP TKIP
   wpa-group CCMP TKIP
        wpa-ssid "MiRouter"
        wpa-psk "4444333221"
iface default inet dhcp
```

Comment: DO NOT add additional detail into comments - EDIT into your question. `ssh` is NOT enabled by default. Post output of `ip a`

Comment: first test ... after pi has booted, what do you see in the output of `ifconfig` - do you even see a `wlan0` (or `wlx????????????`) device? is its IP address `192.168.31.94` like you've mentioned in a comment below? Check the output of `dmesg` - any errors pertaining to wifi device there? You haven't specified what wifi dongle you are using. You may have one not compatible with RPi

Comment: nup it used to work before when i have configuration done on /etc/network/interfaces but it was done for only one network. when i research for multiple network, most of the user recommended the configuration in wpa_supplement.conf and i tried the same and it's not working now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Stretch you SHOULD NOT modify `/etc/network/interfaces` (indeed you can just delete it).

Your `wpa_supplicant` looks OK, although it contains un-necessary lines.

You should set Wi-Fi country e.g `country=AU` - not sure if absolutely necessary for Pi2, but still should be set.

See [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) which shows the correct contents of the files.

Comment: I switched to the default /etc/network/interfaces and removed priority from the wpa_supplicant but its not working still. The wifi dongle gets blinked but wifi is still not working.I get this issue `ssh: connect to host 192.168.31.94 port 22: Operation timed out`

Comment: Did you add your country code?

Comment: sorry i did not add the country code

Comment: So is it working with the correct country code?